# log4j - logging for my package is not working

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j

I am having a problem passing package specific logs to a seperate log file using log4j. it creates the log file but does not write Logger.log messages.

Here is my log4j.xml look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
    <appender name="file.appender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="${jboss.server.home.dir}/log/mainLog.log"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="5MB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="20"/>
        <layout class="com.util.PrettyHTMLLayout"/>
    </appender>

    <appender name="console.appender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.tson.dev.pbuild" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="console.appender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="file.appender"/>
    </logger>
     <root>
        <priority value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="console.appender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="file.appender"/>
   </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

I get below error on JBoss startup in boot.log

```
ERROR [STDERR] log4j:ERROR Failed to flush writer,
00:59:29,681 ERROR [STDERR] java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor
00:59:29,681 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
00:59:29,682 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:282)
00:59:29,682 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:202)
00:59:29,682 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:272)
00:59:29,682 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:276)
00:59:29,682 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:122)
00:59:29,682 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:212)
00:59:29,682 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.log4j.helpers.QuietWriter.flush(QuietWriter.java:59)
00:59:29,682 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.writeFooter(WriterAppender.java:361)
00:59:29,682 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.close(WriterAppender.java:206)
00:59:29,683 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.finalize(AppenderSkeleton.java:144)
00:59:29,683 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.invokeFinalizeMethod(Native Method)
00:59:29,683 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:83)
00:59:29,683 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:14)
00:59:29,683 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:172)

and when i access the application i get below

ERROR [STDERR] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-2) log4j:ERROR No output stream or file set for the appender named [null].
```

Can someone please help me.

Comment: Where do you have `jboss.server.home.dir` defined?

Comment: its defined at /jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default

Comment: Please help me to resolve this issue..

Comment: I'm not too familiar with that version of JBoss AS. However, it looks like for some reason the file descriptor seems bad. I'm not sure what would cause that. Maybe the file has been deleted or something.

Comment: James, file gets created (0 Kb) but nothing gets written to it.

Comment: It looks like it's an issue with the file descriptor. I'm not sure what the issue would be.